# How to set proxy for only a webview,not for all webviews in application on Android

Tags: android, webview, proxy

I set proxy for webview via interfaces Provided by ProxyController,If a proxy is set, all webviews in the application will be affected.

How to set proxy for only one webview, because other webviews not need to use the proxy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.